# Why does LinkedIn have JavaScript and Rest API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Why does LinkedIn has [REST and JavaScript API samples](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis)? One is a JavaScript api and the other is rest api. What purpose does having 2 api's serve? Is one better than the other? Have you used any and faced problems?

Which is more efficient in terms of information retrieval time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LinkedIn has created 2 sets of API to provide greater flexibility to developers.

Javascript API provides a rich and easy-to-use library to quickly create dynamic User Interface in web browsers. It use OAuth 2 to easily authorize users.

Whereas REST API is programming language & platform agnostic. It uses XML/JSON format and its simple. But this requires developers to create their own User Interface. It uses OAuth 1.0a to authorize users.